# The visibility of a Text Box is seen in the code view but design view

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a Text Box in my Table in SSRS 2008.

In the Design View, when I check the `Visibility -> Hidden` property of this Text Box from the Properties window on the right, it is set to: `FALSE`. The visibility of the column where the Text Box locates is set to: `SHOW`. There is no grouping for this column/text box.

However, when I go to Code View, I see there is a visibility property is assigned as an expression like below:
[image]

When I run the report, the line we see in the code view is working, the table is hiding the Text Box based on the parameter (Filter) value. But somehow we do not see this rule in the design view, we have to specifically look and see from the code view. I could not find why it is happening. Anyone experienced a similar issue? Do I missing something or some area to check in the design view? Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sometimes happens when design changes or dataset changes are done that the designer can;t handle properly. I had a recent instance where the name of a column in the dataset had changed and I removed a column group at the same time.

I ended up with a property like you have that could not be accessed thru the designer.

I simply deleted TablixMembers group (via the code view) as it had no other data in it (yours is the same) and then applied the hidden expression again via the designer. Everything worked as expected after that.